White screen on the main display after upgrading to 24.04
I've upgraded to 24.04 from 23.10 and now my main display is white. I've got a laptop with and an external monitor via hdmi and the laptop screen is totally white apart from the menu on the top. But the external monitor is absolutely fine. I switched the main display to the external monitor and now it's white with the top menu and laptop screen is normal. The programmes are launched fine, but I cannot see them on the white screen. Though I know that they are there by doing Alt+Tab. I tried to reinstall the Nvidia drivers but it didn't resolve the problem. Also I've read somewhere about adding nomodeset in grub but it didn't solve it either. Any ideas?

Looks like it was a problem with Gnome. I have reset it by
dconf reset -f /org/gnome

and everything got sorted.
